# javascript funcion masMenos

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo el siguiente ejercicios:

Necesitamos una función masMenos que reciba un array y devuelva otro con los siguientes tres números:

```
En la primera posición, la fracción de números que son positivos
En la segunda posición, la fracción de números que son cero
En la última posición, la fracción de números que son negativos
```

Por ejemplo, masMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]) debería devolver [0.5, 0.25, 0.25], dado que hay 50% de positivos, 25% de ceros, y 25% de negativos. Escribí la función masMenos

Esto fue lo que yo hice:

```js
function masMenos(numeros){
    var positivos = 0;
    var cero = 0;
    var negativos = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        if (numeros[i] > 0) {
            positivos+=1 }
        if (numeros[i] < 0) {
            negativos+=1 }
        if (numeros[i] == 0) {
            cero+=1 }
    }
    var suma = positivos + negativos + cero; 
    var porcentaje = [positivos / suma, negativos / suma, cero / suma]; 
    return porcentaje; 
}
console.log(masMenos([1,2,0,-1]));
```

Pero me da este error:
    La función masMenos([0,0,0,0]) debe retornar [0,1,0]
    La función masMenos([1,0]) debe retornar [0.5,0.5,0]

Quiero ayuda para saber que está mal. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esta bien, solo te habias liado con el puesto de los ceros y los negativos al construir el array, aqui puedes comprobar que todo funciona bien intercambiando esos puestos:

```js
function masMenos(numeros){
var positivos = 0;
var cero = 0;
var negativos = 0;
for (var i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
    if (numeros[i] > 0) {
        positivos+=1 }
    if (numeros[i] < 0) {
        negativos+=1 }
    if (numeros[i] == 0) {
        cero+=1 }
}
var suma = positivos + negativos + cero; 
var porcentaje = [positivos / suma,  cero / suma,negativos / suma]; 
return porcentaje; 
}
console.log("La función masMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]) debería devolver [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]");
console.log("La función masMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]) y devuelve "+masMenos([1,2,0,-1]));
console.log("La función masMenos([0,0,0,0]) debe retornar [0,1,0]");
console.log("La función masMenos([0,0,0,0]) devuelve " + masMenos([0,0,0,0]));
console.log("La función masMenos([1,0]) debe retornar [0.5,0.5,0]");
console.log("La función masMenos([1,0]) devuelve "+masMenos([1,0]));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahorá si me funcionó!!

Comment: De nada, estamos aquí para ayudarnos, por favor, si lo ves conveniente considera marcar la respuesta correcta que te ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en el orden. Tiene: positivos, negativos, cero.

```
 var porcentaje = [positivos / suma, negativos / suma, cero / suma];
```

```js
function masMenos(numeros){
    var positivos = 0;
    var cero = 0;
    var negativos = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        if (numeros[i] > 0) {
            positivos+=1 }
        if (numeros[i] < 0) {
            negativos+=1 }
        if (numeros[i] == 0) {
            cero+=1 }
    }
    var suma = numeros.length; 
    var porcentaje = [positivos / suma, cero / suma, negativos / suma]; 
    return porcentaje; 
}
console.log(masMenos([0,0,0,0]));
```